# Remove leading zero elements from array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I would like to remove the leading `0` elements to get this:

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

What's the best way to do this in Ruby? I have come up with a solution, but it doesn't feel as elegant as it could be:

```
count = 0
a.each do |element|
  break if element != 0
  count += 1
end
a = a[count..-1]
```

I feel like there might be a clean one-liner for this.

Comment: I added a benchmark that may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `drop_while`.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while

```
a = a.drop_while {|x| x == 0}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir. `a = a.drop_while {|x| x == 0}`

Comment: @matt interesting, but is not surgery syntax drop_while? any better or worst performance?

Comment: I added a benchmark that may be of interest.

Answer (score 6):

I would use:

```
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0].drop_while(&:zero?)
 #=> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
until a[0] != 0 do a.shift end
```

Comment: I added a benchmark that may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

For speed, I'd put my money on the following.

```
def drop_leading_zeros(arr)
  i = arr.index(1)
  i.nil? ? arr : arr[i..-1]
end
```

```
drop_leading_zeros [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]  #=> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0] 
drop_leading_zeros [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  #=> []
```

---

Let's do a benchmark.

```
require 'fruity'

def test(n)
  arr = Array.new(n-1, 0) << 1
  puts
  compare do
    matt        { a = arr.dup; a.drop_while { |x| x == 0} }
    spickermann { a = arr.dup; a.drop_while(&:zero?) }
    Jürgen      { a = arr.dup; a.shift until a[0] != 0; a }
    Cary        { a = arr.dup; i = a.index(1); i.nil? ? a : a[i..-1] }
  end
end
```

`test(n)` compares the four calculations for an array of size `n` whose last element equals `1` and all other elements equal `0`. I've included `a = arr.dup` to each code snippet because some some would mutate `arr` if that was not done.

```
test(3)
Running each test 16384 times. Test will take about 1 second.
Jürgen is faster than matt by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
matt is similar to Cary
Cary is similar to spickermann
```

```
test(10)
Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 1 second.
Cary is faster than Jürgen by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
Jürgen is faster than matt by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
matt is faster than spickermann by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
```

```
test(1_000)
Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
Cary is faster than Jürgen by 5x ± 0.1
Jürgen is faster than matt by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
matt is similar to spickermann
```

```
test(10_000)
Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
Cary is faster than Jürgen by 6x ± 0.1
Jürgen is faster than matt by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
matt is similar to spickermann
```

```
test(100_000)
Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
Cary is faster than Jürgen by 6x ± 0.1
Jürgen is faster than matt by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
matt is similar to spickermann
```

```
test(1_000_000)
Running each test once. Test will take about 3 seconds.
Cary is faster than Jürgen by 6x ± 0.1
Jürgen is faster than matt by 10.000000000000009% ± 1.0%
matt is similar to spickermann
```

Comment: Very interesting. Seems like you have to decide between readability and performance...

Comment: @spickerman, I expected `index` to be fast because it is invoked with an argument rather than a block.